# Levenshtein edit distance with separator for multi-character units

Tags: r, levenshtein-distance

I have searched through R functions `adist`, `agrep`, `match`, and `stringdist`, but have not found a method to calculate edit distance with a separator.

Existing edit distance:

```
“that” & ”fat” = 2  i.e., adist("that","fat")
```

Desired function would use a separator to denote multi-character units:

```
“th.a.t” & ”f.a.t” = 1
```

Comment: Is this what you're after: `sum(do.call(mapply, c("!=", strsplit(c("th.a.t", "f.a.t"), "\\."))))`? (split both strings, compare substring by substring and sum differences)

Comment: It looks like its missing something to deal with variation in lengths: sum(do.call(mapply, c("!=", strsplit(c("th.a.t.s", "f.a.t"), "\\.")))) ...the added 's' led to this error, "In (function (FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)  : longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levenshtein distance is easy to implement, so just calculate it. Here's a quick no guarantee version of the Wagner-Fischer algorithm (see Wikipedia)

```
vecLeven <- function(s, t) {
  d <- matrix(0, nrow = length(s) + 1, ncol=length(t) + 1)
  d[, 1] <- (1:nrow(d)) - 1
  d[1,] <- (1:ncol(d))-1
  for (i in 1:length(s))  {
    for (j in 1:length(t)) {
      d[i+1, j+1] <- min(
        d[i, j+1] + 1, # deletion
        d[i+1, j] + 1, # insertion
        d[i, j] + if (s[i] == t[j]) 0 else 1 # substitution
      )
    }
  }

    d[nrow(d), ncol(d)]
}

sepLeven <- function(s, t, sep=".") {
  mapply(vecLeven, 
         strsplit(s, sep, fixed=TRUE), 
         strsplit(t, sep, fixed=TRUE))
}

sepLeven(c("th.a.t", "t.e.s.t"), c("f.a.t", "f.e.t"), sep=".")
# output: [1] 1 2
```

Comment: That's great! Just a note on your final line for people that might search for this, that output is incorrect. sepLeven("th.a.t", "t.e.s.t")
[1] 3

Comment: Not quite; the function is vectorized. If you run my test, it does not compare "th.a.t" with "t.e.s.t" and "f.a.t" with "f.e.t", but instead compares "th.a.t" with "f.a.t" and "t.e.s.t" with "f.e.t". I e. the first element of the first parameter is compared with the first element of the second parameter, the second element in the first parameter with the second element in the second parameter and so on. It's irrelevant if both only contain one element, but this way allows you to do it for a whole data.frame with a single command, or compare a vector of strings to a single target etc.

Comment: I've tried for the last hour to figure out how to run the sepLeven with apply or lapply and am not sure why I get: Error in strsplit(t, sep, fixed = TRUE) : 
  argument "t" is missing, with no default. Any ideas? I have not problem in using adist in the same manner.

Comment: @user1936965 Couple things: if `sepLeven` is the answer you were looking for, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer. Second, consider asking as a new question (`how to use apply with custom function`) since it's kind of outside the scope of your original question

Comment: You don't need to use `apply* or `lapply`, the function has a built-in apply through `mapply`. If you have a vector or list of strings you want to compare against another string, or pairwise against a vector of strings, just do `vecLeven(theVectorOrList, theStringVectorOrList)`

Comment: Thank you again for clarifying, sepLeven(theVectorOrList, theStringVectorOrList) worked on at data.frame